# Server ran out of HD room

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, unix, filesystems

A rogue script brought my centOS-based server to its knees and resulted in 0 bytes of HD room left. I since fixed the issue and everything seems to be running normally.

So my question is, what should I do to check/fix for damage to the file system? Does hitting 0 bytes available necessarily mean a file system corruption?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why should there be any corruption?  It just means the file system is full.

Comment: thanks @Nate - I just assumed that if the filesystem filled up, this could cause bigger issues other than a lack of disk space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filesystem should be fine. You'll probably have some gaps in log files and it's possible that scripts/programs that aren't scrupulous about checking the success of writes may have lost data but that's all.

You might want to check that logging (apache and syslog) is working correctly after you fixed the space problem - a service reload should be all that is required if not.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Haldane - so I guess the answer is that I should be fine if I'm writing to logs and and my services restart fine.